# Merging 2 gridviews into one generated PDF file using iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, gridview, itext

I'm using 2 gridviews. The first one has paging enabled, and the number of rows allowed per page is one. The second gridview takes values from the first row as time range, and everytime I change the page on gridview1 the second GV changes it's content automatically based on GV1's values.

Previously, I was able to generate a PDF file using iTextSharp with only one gridview and no paging enabled. But now I'm struggling first of all with the paging enabled, and second with merging both gridviews into one pdf file.

Anybody know how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** This is the code I use to generate a PDF file from a gridview using iTextSharp.

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.html;
using iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser;

StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
gvReportes.AllowPaging = false;
gvReportes.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");
gvReportes.HeaderRow.Style.Add("font-size", "7.20px");
gvReportes.HeaderRow.Style.Add("color", "#284775");
gvReportes.Style.Add("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;");
gvReportes.Style.Add("font-size", "6px");
gvReportes.RenderControl(htextw);
Document document = new Document();
string path = "path.pdf";
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
StringReader str = new StringReader(stw.ToString());
HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(document);
htmlworker.Parse(str);
Response.Write(document);
document.Close();
```

And this is how the gridviews are displayed, as you can see the values "Salida" and "Llegada" on GV1 work as a time range to display data on GV2.

[image: Gridviews]

Comment: you need to post some code for others to help you. also point out which part of the code is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear(); //this clears the Response of any headers or previous output
        Response.Buffer = true; //ma
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=injoin.pdf");

        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);

        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

        pdfDoc.Open();

        htmlparser.Parse(sr);

        pdfDoc.Close();

        Response.Write(pdfDoc);

        Response.End();  

    }
```

Comment: Consider adding a bit more of an explanation instead code only.